# SQL Database Design Approach

Tags: sql

Approach 1- We have a different factories with the same code base structure. But different factories are storing different set of information like Factory A stores Parameter and its Values eg: Current = 110 and Factory B stores different parameter (eg:- Voltage = 10, etc) and its values. So we decided to go with different tables approach for different factories to avoid NULL values and defined Parameter as Columns (Eg:- Table_For_Factory_A Columns  are Current, ParameterB,etc) Values of these parameters are stored as Rows in the database. If there are 10 parameters then one row was inserting into the database with its values.

Approach 2- Now, We are seeing a different approach from one of our team member saying that Keep the one Big table for factories with differentiating column called (Factory Name) and stored the Parameter and its values in one single table  as rows.So if there are 10 parameters for one factory then insert the 10 parameters and its values as rows in tables where the table is growing exponentially.

Eg:- Table Columns are Parameter, value, FactoryName,...)

Kindly suggest which approach is better and why.we believed keeping the table smaller and minimal inserts will boast the performance and load on the database server. Also in Approach 2 parameter name gets repeated in every time user updates or saves it which is not good as per normalization. Please help us in deciding the approach.

Answer (score -1):

```
factories table
---------------
id 
name
...


parameters table
----------------
id
name
...


factory_values table
--------------------
factory_id
parameter_id
value
```